# how to change the value using setsate in Select tag if the number of select tag is changeable

Tags: reactjs, select

I am new in react and I am using select tag to select answers to questions and this select tag changes based on the number of questions which can modify too ..
I want to save the selection of each answer with its question .. I hope someone can help me in this :

```js
<Card>
  <Card.Header>
    <Card.Title as='h5'>
      Select questions and their answer to create the decision tree
    </Card.Title>
  </Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>
    { Object.entries(this.state.liste).map(([ke,values]) => {
      return (                            
        <div className="row ">
          <div className="col-xl-11">
             <h6 className="align-items-center float-left">{ke}</h6>
             <div className="progress-bar progress-c-theme" role="progressbar" style={{width: '0%'}} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"/>
             <div className="text-right">
               <div className="col-md-11" style={{ width: '130px', height: '20px', top: '-20px', right: '-400px' }}>
                 <select name = "secondSelectt" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                   {Object.values(values).map(key=>{
                     return (
                       <option id={key}>{key}</option>
                     );
                   })}
                 </select>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div className="progress m-t-30 m-b-20" style={{height: '1px'}}>
               <div className="progress-bar progress-c-theme" role="progressbar" style={{width: '0%'}} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"/>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      )})
    }
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add value to your options. And a default value to your select. that will come from your states. (handleChange) will update this state.

```
this.state = {
    secondSelectt: '',
    liste: [1,2,3,4,5],
}

handleChange({target: { name, value }}) {
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

Your new code.

```
<Card>
    <Card.Header>
        <Card.Title as='h5'>Select questions and their answer to create the decision tree</Card.Title>
    </Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>
        {this.state.liste.map(number => {
            return (
                <div className="row ">
                    <div className="col-xl-11">
                        <h6 className="align-items-center float-left">{ke}</h6>
                        <div className="progress-bar progress-c-theme" role="progressbar"
                            style={{ width: '0%' }} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" />
                        <div className="text-right">
                            <div className="col-md-11" style={{ width: '130px', height: '20px', top: '-20px', right: '-400px' }}>
                                <select name="secondSelectt" value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}>
                                    {Object.values(values).map(key => { return (<option key={key} value={key}>{key}</option>) })}
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="progress m-t-30 m-b-20" style={{ height: '1px' }}>
                            <div className="progress-bar progress-c-theme" role="progressbar"
                                style={{ width: '0%' }} aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>)
        })
        }
    </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

This is the specific change I've made.

```
this.state = {
    liste: [1,2,3,4,5]
}

<select 
    name="secondSelectt" 
    value={this.state.selectedValue} 
    onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
>
   {liste.map(number => <option key={number} value={number}>{number}</option>)}
</select>
```

Comment: I added these couples of lines and when I change the value it stays the same and in the console I got this warning : SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: Event, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}

Comment: what was the use of defining liste in the state?

Comment: How do you define the handleChange function please ?